# COM interface c# marshalling array of arrays

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, com, marshalling

I have a COM server written in C++ that should interface with a client written in C#.
The C++ COM server exports interface functions to a structure that holds an array of structures with an array inside

```
struct InnerStruct  { int innerArray[ 100 ]; }
struct OuterStruct  { int dummy; InnerStruct outerArray[ 2 ]; }
```

So the structs have fixed size.

The IDL descriptions are

```
HRESULT SetStruct( [in] const OuterStruct* par, [out, retval] int code );
HRESULT GetStruct( [out] OuterStruct* par, [out, retval] int code );
```

The IDL compile fine and I can see the structure in the C# client.

The problem is that when I call the interface functions from the C# client I only get/set the values in the first InnerStruct in the OuterStruct.
The second InnerStruct only holds garbage.

The C# debugger shows the right structure for the OuterStruct and knows there are 2 InnerStruct inside the OuterStruct.

In C# the declaration of the interface functions come from a server metafile, so it is not easy to change the description.

I have tried to set a size_is() on the in and out parameters but the MIDL compiler will not accept that.

Can I set up some specific marshaling on the parameters or how do I solve the problem of getting the complete OuterStruct trough COM?

Comment: 1) Are you sure that MIDL compiles without warnings (for example, about ignored specifiers)? Since it is strange to see `out` argument that is not a pointer. 2) "_I have tried to set a size_is()_" `size_is` would serve a purpose if you would pass in multiple `OuterStruct`s, while, if I understand everything correctly, you are passing just a single one (even then, `size_is` require additional arguments specifying the size). I have never dabbled with such structs in COM. May try to do so later today.

Comment: I try to write [in, size_is(1000)].

Comment: The error code I get back is

Comment: midl : error MIDL2471: Some attributes and/or data types in the idl and/or included/imported idl files can not be represented in the type library: size_is/max_is

Comment: 1) "_I try to write [in, size_is(1000)]_" Try to write it, on where? On `[in] const OuterStruct* par`? If so, you would be expected to pass in `OuterStruct par[1000]` into it, which, I doubt, is your intention. Even then, I never used hardcoded values for `size_is`, so I don't know if using hardcoded values are supported for `size_is`. 2) Make sure that your idl compiles without warnings. 3) You can edit your comments, so you don't comment spam.

Comment: Structs are quite tricky due to structure packing rules, formally you must use IRecordInfo to access their members.  Use sizeof in your C++ code and Marshal.SizeOf() in your C# code to double-check that the sizes agree.

Comment: @Hans Passant
How do I use IRecordInfo and marshall.SizeOf()?

Answer (score 0):

In my IDL file I have tried to write

```
typedef [transmit_as(OuterStructAliasType)] OuterStruct* HelpType;
```

and keep the other declarations as

```
HRESULT SetStruct( [in] const OuterStruct* par, [out, retval] int code );
HRESULT GetStruct( [out] OuterStruct* par, [out, retval] int code );
```

where in my C++ code I have defined

```
typedef struct OuterStructAliasType
{
    char    dummy[ sizeof( OuterStruct )];
} OuterStructAliasType;
```

This seems to work.
There maybe are other ways to the trick.
Please tell me it they are smarter or better.